# Is there any approach proof for Legendre conjecture or it is completed solved?

Tags: number-theory, conjectures

[Legendre conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_conjecture) stated that:for every *x* there exists a prime number between $x^2$ and $x^2+2x+1$ .then Is there any approach proof for legender conjecture or it is completed solved ?

Comment: Please replace *legender* with *Legendre*. The existence of a prime in any interval of the form $[x^2,(x+1)^2]$ for any sufficiently large $x$ still is an open problem. What are you interested in, exactly? Standard techniques for proving weaker claims are known as *sieve methods*. *Halberstam* is a good reference for them.

Answer (score 0):

From the introductory paragraph of your link

> as of 2017, the conjecture has neither been proved nor disproved.

Comment: but what about  approach proof ?, and we are in 2018